# How to scrape ordered and unordered lists in wikipedia using rvest relative to a header

Tags: html, r, xml, rvest

I'm wanting to scrape the events from several countries from Wikipdia and place each individual event into a row of a table. A certain data can have one event (where there is a single main bullet point) or multiple events (where there are "sub bullet points")

1. I'm having trouble with is how to grab both the ordered and unordered lists at once and separating them cleanly. The code below will grab the "sub bullets", but not the "main" ones. And if I change the code to exclude the `/li` then it will place the "sub bullets" into a single cell. **I was wondering if there was a way to separate the "main" and "sub bullet points" more easily.**
2. There appear to be slight differences in the html layout for pages that contain events for different countries. Is it possible to specify an xml path based on a header (rather than a relative or absolute position) and then grab the elements after that? Unfortunately, being so new to html, I'm not quite sure how to do that or if it is even possible. **Is it possible to find the header "Events by month", find the header "January" and then get all bullet points and sub bullet points in separate cells of a table?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou

```
# This gets the sub bullet points of the events, but not the main ones 
page <- xml2::read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_in_the_United_States")
month_data = page %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/ul[3]/li") %>% 
        html_text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This webpage is has no structure, it is just one long list of tags without clearly separating the different sections out.

This is partial solution:

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

page <- xml2::read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_in_the_United_States")
lineitems <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/ul[3]/li")

#Count the number of child ul nodes
subcount <- lineitems %>% html_node("ul") %>% xml_length()

output <- lapply(1:length(subcount), function(i) {
   if(subcount[i] == 0 ){
      out <- lineitems[i]   %>%  html_text()
   }
   else {
      out <-  lineitems[i] %>% html_node("ul") %>% 
                               html_nodes(xpath=".//li") %>% html_text()
   }
   out
})
#name the list items with the data
names(output) <- lineitems %>% html_node("a") %>% 
                            html_attr("title")
#a list for each date
output
```

I didn't have the time or patience to refine this.  You may have a easier time trying to select the nodes based on the available attributes instead of the particular html/xml tags.

Comment: Thankyou ! Didn't realize it would be so tough. Your partial solution was very helpful.